# Can you use fractional vCPUs with GAE Flexible Environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm transitioning an application from GCE to GAE Flexible. It's currently running in a g1-small instance which is plenty for my needs, however when I try to specify a g1-small instance in my `app.yaml`:

```
resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 1.7
```

I can deploy but there's no indication that a smaller instance is actually being used.

After deploying, there's no indication that my app is running with the smaller instance size.

How can I use fractional vCPUs with the flexible environment? Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?  I believe this could be caused from specifying cpu cores without specifiying memory as well. Try:           resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10

Comment: Just realized I posted the reference app.yaml and not mine. It should read cpu 0.5. I'll update the question and also add the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to use shared (fractional) CPUs on App Engine Flexible at the moment; The number of CPUs you specify must be [an even number between 2 and 96](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#cpu). (If it's not the default value of 1)

There is an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/62011060) for shared CPU instances on the Public Issue Tracker which you can star or add to in order to show your interest in that feature.

Note that there is also no existing feature that lets you directly specify App Engine Standard instance classes or Compute Engine machine types to use in App Engine Flexible.